# check that if email exists in data base or not

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, android-studio

i want to add user to database if Gmail doen't exist this method give Gmail and password from android app can you help me how check it??

```
function addUser($gmail, $password){
$connection = mysqli_connect(DataBaseManager::HOST,DataBaseManager::USER,DataBaseManager::PASSWORD,DataBaseManager::DATABASENAME);

mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");       
$sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO users(gmail , password )VALUES('$gmail','$password')";

if (mysqli_query($connection, $sqlCommand)) {
      return true;
} else {
      return false;
}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is giving you trouble?  Have you actually tried anything to accomplish this?

Comment: no i dont have error its true... i only want to now with which method i can search data base to find if email exist or not

Comment: You need to run a `SELECT` query.  There are plenty of SQL tutorials out there.  This isn't really a "how do I write a simple query" place.  SO is for when you have something that you've tried, and it is either generating errors or an unexpected result.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can query this to know if a user is already registered.

```
SELECT gmail
FROM users
WHERE gmail = '$gmail'
```

If you have 1 row returned, so this user is already registered.

Once you find if this user exists, you can do your query with the `INSERT` clause.

Comment: @BabakRostami and other future readers keep in mind that doing this will introduce a possible race condition in your website/application.. Ideally you should also add a unique key on the column in the database to prevent duplicates..

Comment: I don't understand your comment Dharman. Also you can suggest an edit. The answer is good, maybe there is another way to respond, but it not deserve a downvote.